# How to pop-up the alert message and tell user / throwback the error message for the user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image]i want to tell the users where is the problem occurs so that they can delete the data, it's something like throwback and tell them what's actually cause the problem of deleting the data from the database. Can someone help me to figure out like how ?

My destroy function coding is as below :

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $status = 'success';
    $statusMsg = 'Data Deleted';

    try {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->delete();

    } catch (QueryException  $e) {
        $status = 'success';
        $statusMsg = $e;
        return  back();

    }
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $category->delete();
    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with($status, $statusMsg);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are close. Try this:

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $status = 'success';
    $statusMsg = 'Data Deleted';

    try {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->delete();
    } catch (QueryException  $e) {
        $status = 'success';
        $statusMsg = $e;

        return redirect()->back()->with($status, $statusMsg);
    }

    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with($status, $statusMsg);
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, i have tried and it says ( Exception
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed ) ... i have upload a picture , please help me review it and give me suggestion on it